# Create UDP to TCP bridge with socat/netcat to relay control commands for vlc media-player

Tags: tcp, bridge, udp, packet, socat

The UDP - must listen on port.
The TCP - must connect to a server.

I tried `netcat` and `socat`.

```
nc -v -u -l -p 3333 | nc -v 127.0.0.1 50000

socat -v UDP-LISTEN:3333,fork TCP:localhost:50000
```

Both work -- they delivered the message -- but the line is not ended.
VLC will only take the command if I close netcat/socat.

I monitored the connection with `sockettest` and the messages are one after another in the same line, like this:

```
playpausestopexitadd
```

I need the line to be ended so that the message transmitted looks like this:

```
play
stop
exit
add
```

Maybe the packet is not ended?

I am wondering if `nc` or `socat` have options to send the packet/end line after a certain amount of time.

If I add `\n` to the output as suggested by @roaima, I get `play\nstop\nplay\n` on a single line.

Comment: How are you sending the command to the bridge? Is there any reason you cannot include the `\n` in the data that you send?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect your problem is more because whatever sends the UDP packets is not adding a newline character the commands (as in they should send `"play\n"` and not just `"play"`).

In any case, if you want a new TCP connection to be created for each of the UDP packets, you should use `udp-recvfrom` instead of `udp-listen` in `socat`:

```
socat -u udp-recvfrom:3333,fork tcp:localhost:50000
```

Then every UDP packet should trigger one TCP connection that is only brought up to send the content of the packet and then closed.

Test by doing:

```
echo play | socat -u - udp-sendto:localhost:3333
```

(which sends a UDP packet whose payload contains the 5 bytes `"play\n"`).

Comment: thank for response, these commands are send via a playout program Playbox Airbox. is a profesional playout program for broadcasting. 
and u are right if i write `play\n` i get exactly that `play\nstop\nplay\n`  
its sending the text disregarding the `\n`  , `udp-recvfrom` works like a charm thank you !